# Why aren't my elements floating the right way?

Tags: html, css, css-float, wrapper

Here is my website:

http://violetoeuvre.com/

I'm confused as to why my code isn't behaving the way I want it to. I'd like the side wrapper (side_nav_wrapper) to be on the left side of the page, with a left margin of about 200px. This works when I don't specify a float. (Shouldn't it work if I specify float:left;?)

Then I'd like the photo box (home_photo) to float to the right of this. (Basically it would start where the C in Carmichael is). But, it keeps being pushed to the bottom. I've tried all kinds of float scenarios and can't figure it out.

I'd like the text box (home_text) to go below the photo box and to the right of the side navigation. Why isn't this working!

(top wrapper in black and white is working just fine)

Thanks in advance. Here is my css:

```
/* Wrapper - Main *********/

.top_wrapper{ 
        display:block;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
        width:100%;
        height: 200px;
        margin-top: 0px;
}

.top_emma {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 121px;
}

/* Top Navigation *********/

.wrapper_nav_box { 
        float: left;
        width:686px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        margin-left: 10px;
}

.nav_box_l {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:247px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 169px;
}

.nav_box_m {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:165px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 169px;
}

.nav_box_r {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:219px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 169px;
}

/* Side Navigation ***********************/

.side_nav_wrapper {
        display:block;
        background: rgba(255,255,0,.5);
        width:200px;
        height: 2000px;
        margin-left: 104px;
}

.side_nav_about {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        background: rgba(255,0,255,.5);
        width:200px;
        height: 100px;
}

.side_nav_writing {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        background: rgba(0,255,255,.5);
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
}

.side_nav_contact {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        background: rgba(100,255,255,.5);
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
}
/* Photo Box on Home Page ************************/

.home_photo { 
        display:block;
        float: right;
        width: 980px;
        height: 400px;
        background: rgba(0,0,255, .5);
        margin-left: 322px;

}

/* Text Box on Home Page */

.home_text{ 
        display:block;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        width:980px;
        height: 250px;
        margin-left: 322px;

}
```

and html:

```
<div class="top_wrapper">

<!-- Top _____________________________________________________-->

    <div id="emma_home" class="top_wrapper">
            <div class="top_emma">
                <a href="index.html">Emma Carmichael</a>
            </div>

        <!--- Top Navigation Menu ______________________________________________-->

        <div class="wrapper_nav_box">
            <div class="nav_box_l" id="nav_menu">
                <a href="writing.html">WRITING  |</a> 
            </div>
            <div class="nav_box_m" id="nav_menu">
                <a href="http://tumblr.com">BLOG  |</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_box_r" id="nav_menu">
                <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Side Navigation__________________________________-->
    <div class="side_nav_wrapper">
        <div class="side_nav_about">about</div>
        <div class="side_nav_writing">writing</div>
        <div class="side_nav_contact">contact</div>
    </div>
<!-- Photo __________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_photo">
    </div>

<!-- About___________________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_text">
        <p>Emma Carmichael is a writer and editor based in Brooklyn, NY, although she hails from Brattleboro, VT. Emma graduated from Vassar College in 2010 with a degree in Urban Studies; the theme of her thesis about contextualizing female rappers, “XXX,” was prescient of her interest in writing about women in the media at The Awl and elsewhere. A point guard for Vassar’s Basketball team from 2006 – 2008, Carmichael has also explored sports writing and women in sports as a writer and then editor at Deadspin.com, a child of Gawker Media. From March 2012 to March 2013, Emma was the managing editor of Gawker.com, a new position at the site; she currently holds the position of Managing Editor at Deadspin.com.
    </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you want a side bar on the left and the content to the right of the side bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Now that I think of it, you probably forgot to close `top_wrapper` as it seems like your layout is missing a closing `div` tag somewhere. So, the "quick fix" would be to do what I recommended below, but really you should try to validate your `HTML` first.

Since `side_nav_wrapper` is placed **inside** `top_wrapper` (may want to rethink this), you need to add a `float: left` to `top_wrapper` as well in order to have the sidebar float to the left the way you want it to.

```
.top_wrapper{
display: block;
background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
margin-top: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: @Claire PS: I've tested this on your site via Chrome dev tools and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you Evan! I cleaned up my divs so that the side wrapper in differentiated. I just made the content in a new wrapper (.content_wrapper) and place the photo box and text box in it. But, it's still not floating to the right! See updated site.

Comment: @Claire Here is how to make it work now:
1. Add a `float: left` to `.top_wrapper`
2. Get rid of `margin-left` on `contact wrapper` (or just make it smaller)

Comment: you mean content wrapper? Ok, I did that, still not working!
I'm finding wrappers and floating to be very confusing. Thanks in advance for your help again.

Comment: If you build a jsFiddle I'll make the changes for you in there so you can see what I mean

Comment: well i just copied the html and css, not sure why the fonts aren't working but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/XqvhE/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26956/discussion-between-evan-and-claire)